# CarrierwaveDirect version filename porting from CarrierWave fog

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, carrierwave, carrierwave-direct

So I've got 9000+ original images, each with 5-7 generated sizes, already stored on S3. Moving production to Heroku and one of the issues we have is timeout on large master images.

Started trying Carrierwave Direct gem to go straight to the S3 store and then process async, but ran into an issue with existing images disappearing as soon as I added the third include line to the base uploader:

```
class BaseUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include CarrierWave::RMagick
  include CarrierWave::ImageOptimizer
  include CarrierWaveDirect::Uploader

  ...
end
```

CarrierwaveDirect changes the filename format (here is the method: https://github.com/dwilkie/carrierwave_direct/blob/29caaa8d399968258299b57c84eac2e5e6fc4cf7/lib/carrierwave_direct/uploader.rb#L153)

The filenames are changed in this manner:

Orig carrierwave gen:
`https://images.patchvault.org/uploads/issue/imageback/629/full_003b_a1_back.png`

CW Direct url gen:
`https://images.patchvault.org/uploads/issue/imageback/629/003b_a1_back_full.png`

So the version name moves from the begining to the end of the uploaded filename. That actually makes sense, but I'm dealing with 2 years and 9k images :)

When I enable `include CarrierWaveDirect::Uploader` in the `BaseUploader` it changes the manner in which urls are generated in the view, and therefore all images 404 (since they no longer exist)

1. What is the best practice here? I'm saving to Fog, but since it's uploading to Heroku's `/tmp`, should I just move the processing to async?
2. Can I revert the behavior by overriding that method or is that a no-go?
3. Is there a way to easily rewrite the images filenames on S3 to the new format or is that a no-go?

Open to other solutions I'm not thinking about as well :)

The path is generated in `base_uploader.rb`:

```
def store_dir
  "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
end
```

Rails 5.2.1, Ruby 2.5.2, Heroku-18 Standard 2x dyno (web) 1x dyno (worker). `images.patchvault.org` is the CNAME for a cloudfront CDN distro on the S3 bucket.